# Why is blockchain.info allowed to have an iOS app but coinbase is not?

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info, coinbase.com, ios

I saw that Coinbase's new wallet app has been [pulled](http://techcrunch.com/2013/11/15/apple-bumps-coinbases-bitcoin-app-from-the-app-store-android-app-lives-on/) from the iOS app store.

Is there anything about the Coinbase wallet app that was different from the [blockchain.info wallet app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/blockchain/id493253309)?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because blockchain.info is just a wallet whereas coinbase actually allows you to buy and sell bitcoins. Exchanging one currency for another (where one is only loosely labeled a currency by the government) is where you get into sketchy regulatory waters. I imagine these are the types of problems apple would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Update: On February 5th, 2014, Apple removed the Blockchain.info app from the app store.

> Apple has removed the world’s most popular bitcoin wallet from its App
>   Store.
>
> Late Wednesday, the tech giant yanked the Blockchain app from the
>   popular mobile app marketplace and did not provide a specific reason,
>   says Nicolas Cary, the CEO of Blockchain.

http://www.wired.com/wiredenterprise/2014/02/blockchain_apple/

Comment: Yet another reason to dump Apple. Why people still buy iPhones must simply be ignorance.